# Response Time out error for reports with big data

Tags: reporting-services, error-handling, timeout, ssrs-2008, html

I am getting the time out errors at below step in code for reports with large data.

```
result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

I tried the below in web.config for that specific page but no help.

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="43200" maxRequestLength="104856"/>
</system.web>
```

Please respond to this if anyone knows the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long does it take to run interactively?

Comment: In SQL Management Studio it is running 10 minutes and showing results but in Report builder though i increased report server time to 1 hour and individual report query time out to 1 hour it is still getting failed and showing time out error after may be 10 minutes.

Comment: You need to find out how long the report takes to run on average. Try increasing the timeout via the SSRS web interface. Highlight/click Manage, and under processing  change the timeout to a high number. Once you know how long it takes on average you can set the value appropriately.